# Hibernate association using non-primary columns as criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I would like a read-only set relation that consists of objects that match non-pk values.

The following example table may illustrate my point:

```
User:
 id<pk>
 username
 alias
 Collection logs (all Log entries with log.useralias=alias and log.status>4)

Log:
 id<pk>
 status
 useralias
 message
```

NOTE: This is just an example, please do not comment on the usefulness of this example.

The reason I need this as a relation is perfomance: I cannot execute a query on the Logs for each User, I need a single query that initializes all the data.

Bonus question: Can this relation be initialized from a HQL query instead of expressing it as a relation?
Something similar to:

```
from User u
  left join fetch Log l into u.logs
  where l.useralias=u.alias and l.status>4
```

EDIT:
Please note that this is different from the Cat example:

```
from Cat as cat
    left join cat.kittens as kitten
        with kitten.bodyWeight > 10.0
```

In this case, the relation from Cat to Kittens is a foregn key->primary key relation, which would make life much simpler. In my question I do not have a foreign key, just non-pk filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName%28%29) has a `referencedColumnName` attribute which allows setting... the referenced column name (i.e. `alias`, in this case).

Hibernate has a [Where](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) annotation allowing to specify a condition, using SQL, that the elements of a collection must verify (i.e. `status > 4`)

Comment: Thanks! I am not using annotations and it seems to me after some googling that there is no equivalent XML config option. Do you know if that is correct?